# There are no nonabelian simple groups with order smaller than $60$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

> Show that there are no nonabelian simple groups with order smaller than $60$.
> (The methods we have discussed up to this point are sufficient to deal with every
> order except for $24$, $36$ and $48$. Here is a hint if $|G| = 36$: Suppose that $G$ has
> distinct Sylow $3$-subgroups $H$ and $K$. What is $|H \cap K|$? What can you say about
> $|N(H \cap K)|$? Find a nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $G$.)

This is my last group theory exercise from the book "Abstract Algebra" by gregory T. Lee. I have already managed to cover all the cases except those mentioned in the comment of the problem. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480558/g-is-non-abelian-simple-group-of-order-100-then-g-cong-a-5) and in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237744/prove-that-there-is-no-nonabelian-simple-group-of-order-less-than-60) answer they use Burnside's theorems and in others that I have seen, group actions. But this material is not in the book and I would like to do it by following the hint that is in it, as this is an elementary way of doing it. I just need an extra hint to get started, any help would be appreciated.

---

Comment: Do you see why $\vert H \cap K \vert = 3$ (and not $1$)?  Hint:  Otherwise, how many elements of $G$ are *not* an element of some $3$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Do they really get along without group actions? Many concrete groups are *defined* in terms of an action and I'd also prefer to have actions available when proving e.g. Sylow

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes. If you want you can take a look at the book, the book tries to the maximum to work with elementary methods

Comment: @RobertShore $|H\cap K|$ is either $1, 3$ or $9$. If it is $9$, then $H=K$, so the the $3$-subgroup is unique and hence normal. If it is $1$, then we have $32$ elements and the $2$-subgroup must be unique. That is, there is a normal subgroup. Thus  $|H\cap K|=3$. Right?

Comment: Now $|N(H\cap K)|$ is either $3, 9$ or $36$. If it is $36$ then $|H\cap K|$ is normal. What about $3$ or $9$?

Comment: I think that in both cases ($ |N(H\cap K)|=3$ or $9$), we have  $|N(H\cap K)|=C|(H\cap K)|$ and therefore $|H\cap K|$ is central. Right?

Comment: Not that.  But do you know that a group of order $9$ (more generally, a group of order $p^2$) has to be abelian?

Comment: @RobertShore Could you please review my answer and tell me exactly where it is missing?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't use the hint, but it's an answer.

Let $\vert G \vert=36=2^2 \cdot 3^2$.  For $G$ to have any chance to be simple, we must have $n_3(G)=4$.  Let $H_1, H_2, H_3, H_4$ be the $3$-Sylow subgroups of $G$.  Then we can define a homomorphism $\varphi:G \to S_4$ via $\varphi(g)(n)=k$, where $g^{-1}H_n g=H_k$. In other words, we let $G$ permute the Sylow subgroups via conjugation.

Consider $\ker(\varphi)$.  We know that $\varphi$ has non-trivial image because the Sylow subgroups are not normal, and therefore can't all be fixed by every element of $G$.  Thus, $\ker(\varphi) \neq G$.  But $36 \gt 24 = \vert S_4 \vert$, so $\varphi$ cannot be injective and it must have non-trivial kernel, which is therefore a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$.