# Are there any nonabelian simple groups of order 60?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

> Prove that there are no nonabelian simple groups of order < 60.

I am studying abstract algebra from Artin and trying some questions and got struck on this.

Let on the contrary there exists a nonabelian simple groups of order <60.

I am at loss of ideas on which result to use and would very much appreciate an outline of solution.

Comment: It is well-known that the alternating group $A_5$ of order $60$ is the smallest nonabelian simple group. But now that you mention it, I don't know a good way to prove it other than brute force of some sort.

Comment: From the answers to the duplicate: "Here's a possibly shorter way to do the problem from "scratch" (assuming only Sylow's theorem, and **not** assuming Burnside's $pq$-theorem)".

Comment: The question is popular, and there are many different answers. But I agree, it is difficult to sort out a suitable answer. For this you need to say what exactly you are allowed to use. Often just writing " I am at loss of ideas" leads to a "close", see also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3237744/prove-that-there-is-no-nonabelian-simple-group-of-order-less-than-60?noredirect=1&lq=1).